# Add sorting to a mongoose find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all, I made list page for some memo.

And I want to load the memo by order the time created memo.

It means just like simple SNS, I want to let them load in stack order.

This is Database Schema added 'created_at'

```
var StatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        id: {type: Number, unique: true, 'default':''},
        ...
        created_at: {type: Date, index: {unique: false}, 'default': Date.now}
    });
```

And I have method for simply listing all of memo. Actually, It is about MongoDB line.

```
StatSchema.static('findAll', function(callback) {
    return this.find({}, callback);
});
```

Then, I want add property 'sort' like

```
this.sort({'created_at':-1})
```

How can I modify the original code?

Answer (score 1):

Omit the callback parameter in your call to `find`, chain your `sort` call to the returned `Query` and then call `exec` to execute the query:

```
StatSchema.static('findAll', function(callback) {
    return this.find({}).sort({'created_at':-1}).exec(callback);
});
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much !